# My visa expires in 2 days. Can I still enter the country?

Tags: visas, air-travel, russia

I booked a flight on the 19th of November, but my Russian visa expires on the 22th of November.

Would there be any problems to board my flight and enter the country?

Comment: I guess visas are valid for the last day, in full, so you actually have closer to four days. What's with number of entries, tho?

Answer (score 6):

No, if you have a valid visa and enter the country in time, and you didn't exceed the number of entries and number of days available in Russia, there wouldn't be any problems. However, you still need to leave the country in time, without staying in for too long before your visa expires.

Comment: You should probably be prepared to prove that you intend to leave the country in time, such as by shoring a return ticket.

Answer (score 0):

As per rules, there should not be any issues entering the country with valid visa (if you are in good terms with previous travel and stay)

I have entered the US with only 3 days available on my visa.

Border security will definitely ask questions about return flight or extension of visa, that you should have a **SOLID** answer (may be a return flight ticket, visa extension application, or similar stuff).

Comment: But in the US, visa validity is independent of duration of stay.  A traveler can arrive on the visa's expiration date and still be admitted for six months or more.  In Russia, this [appears not to be the case](https://ru.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/russian-visas/).  In any event, the practice of another country seems to be of relatively little value in predicting a Russian officer's reaction to the situation presented in the question.

Comment: I dont think US allows to enter with expired visa. I have had lots of questions on entering with 3 days left. Yeah, its not valid to compare across different countries, but again the same rule applies to different immigration officers!

Comment: Of course the US doesn't allow entry with an expired visa (although there are exceptions for short visits to Mexico, Canada, and the Caribbean).  But the visa is valid until the end of its expiration date.  So if your visa expires on October 20th, you can enter on October 20th.  You cannot enter on October 21st.  See for example https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/what-is-a-u-s-visa.html: "'Expiration Date' is the last day you can use your visa to seek entry into the U.S."